# Eclipse process ends unexpectedly

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I've just installed Eclipse Oxygen onto my new laptop using the eclipse installer. When I try to run Eclipse nothing shows up, including the splash screen. When I run it with task manager open I notice that the eclipse process comes up, however, it disappears out of nowhere and nothing ever loads. I've also noticed that while the process is up, it barely uses any resources. Only 0.1% of the RAM. Everything else is 0%.

I've tried running eclipse multiple times. I've reinstalled eclipse, the java jre and the java jdk. Still no progress.

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen with Java JRE 8 Update 101 and Java JDK 8 Update 101. I'm on a 64-bit system and all of my programs are the 64-bit version.
I have added the JDK bin filepath to the path environment variable.

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on.
Thanks =)

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is currently only available as a very early pre-release Milestone build. You might be better to stay with the current release Eclipse Neon.1

Comment: greg is right. use neon.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll give it a go 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some logging would be nice here - have you tried starting eclipse using the `-consoleLog` flag? More details see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F).

Comment: I try to run eclipse in cmd using the -consoleLog flag. Another console window opens and then a window immediately pops up saying that eclipse.exe has stopped working:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/thah2e56twfivcv/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: Ugh, that's a hard one... The only thing I could imagine is to start eclipse directly: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Thanks. That worked.
I went and made a .bat file with that command in and put a link to it on my desktop.